# Sorting an ArrayList of ArrayList having objects inside it

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort an ArrayList of ArrayList which are having objects inside it.
Sorting needs to be done based on some attributes of Objects inside the ArrayList.
It is like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

I want to use Collections's Sort method.

I have tried following but it is displaying error

```
Collections.sort(ccWrapper.colContainer, new Comparator<ArrayList<Object>>() {
public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

return 0;
}});
```

Error:The type Comparator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments >

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post code you have written to solve this

Comment: You probably want a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [this sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: Take a look at all the answers found under the `Related` heading on the right side of this page.

Comment: Implement Comparator based on how you want sorting to be done.

Comment: you can't sort a collection of Object class objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: you cant use collections.sort() if you want to sort in a customized way...

Comment: is there any other way @TheLostMind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you define your own custom `List` that delegates to an `ArrayList` and also happens to be `Comparable`:

```
public class SortableList implements List<Object>, Comparable<SortableList> {
    private ArrayList delegate;

    public SortableList(List list) {
        delegate = new ArrayList(list);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SortableList s) {
        //Do what you need to do with your casts and comparisons
        return 0;
    }

    //And implement all the other methods in List by simply delegating to the ArrayList member variable
}
```

You could also do something similar and less tedious by extending `ArrayList`, but I have a real issue working off a concrete class. Better in my opinion to base your class on higher-level abstractions. But I digress.

Now that `Comparable` is implemented, you can do this:

```
List<SortableList> bigList = new ArrayList<>();
//Do stuff with bigList
Collections.sort(bigList);
```

You don't need `Comparator` since `Comparable` will provide the natural ordering for your custom list. You don't appear to need another means of comparison.

If that isn't clear, we actually did a [tutorial](http://www.vidyasource.com/tutorial/Programming/Java/2013/10/27/comparison-shopping) on `Comparable` and `Comparator` with the files available on [Github](https://github.com/VidyaSource/comparison-shopping). Check it out if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Comparator` or `Comaparable` interfaces with your objects

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be cool if there was some kind of [ComparableComparator](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/help-i-have-comparable-but-i-need.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the compareTo method for the "Object" class that you are storing inside the array lists then use the built-in Collections.sort() on the inner arraylist for each of the outer arraylists.

Comment: "Sorting needs to be done based on some attributes of Objects inside the ArrayList" . The default Collections.sort wont help.. He will have to write code to sort both inner and outer arraylists.

Comment: Oh, it seemed to me that the lists as entities themselves weren't being sorted but the objects in each list. My bad :(

Comment: nevermind... Please be careful the next time around... :)